# Logic issue when saving URLs to file

Tags: c#

What my goal with my piece of code is not to save duplicate domains to a .txt file if a checkbox is ticked.

**Code:**

```
// save to file here
if (footprints.Any(externalUrl.Contains))
{
// Load all URLs into an array ...
var hash = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"Links\" + lblFootprintsUsed.Text));
// Find the domain root url e.g. site.com ...
var root = Helpers.GetRootUrl(externalUrl);

if (chkBoxDoNotSaveDuplicateDomains.Checked == true)
{
    if (!hash.Contains(Helpers.GetRootUrl(externalUrl)))
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamWriter(@"Links\" + lblFootprintsUsed.Text, true))
        {
            // before saving make &amp; to & and get rid of #038; altogether ...
            var newURL = externalUrl.Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("#038;", " ");
            sr.WriteLine(newURL);
            footprintsCount++;
        }
    }
}

if (chkBoxDoNotSaveDuplicateDomains.Checked == false)
{
    if (!hash.Contains(externalUrl))
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamWriter(@"Links\" + lblFootprintsUsed.Text, true))
        {
            // before saving make &amp; to & and get rid of #038; altogether ...
            var newURL = externalUrl.Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("#038;", " ");
            sr.WriteLine(newURL);
            footprintsCount++;
        }
    }
}

}
```

The code above starts off by checking if a certain footprint pattern is found in a URL structure, if it does we load all URLs into a `List` the way `!hash.Contains(externalUrl)` should work is **NOT** to add duplicate URLs to the .txt file, but i can see from testing it **does** add complete duplicate URLs (the first issue) i never noticed this before, then i tried to add `!hash.Contains(Helpers.GetRootUrl(externalUrl))` which should **not** add duplicate domains to the .txt file.

1. - So unchecked, the code should not add duplicate URLs to file.
2. - And checked the code should not add duplicate domains to file.

Both seem to fail, i cannot see any issue in the code as such, is there anyhting i am missing or could do better? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Several things: This code is trivial enough that you should be able to attach a debugger and step through the code to figure out exactly what is going on. Don't compare a boolean variable to `true` or `false`. It's already a boolean, so you can do `if (chkBoxDoNotSaveDuplicateDomains.Checked)` instead of `if (chkBoxDoNotSaveDuplicateDomains.Checked == true)` and `if (!chkBoxDoNotSaveDuplicateDomains.Checked)` instead of `if (chkBoxDoNotSaveDuplicateDomains.Checked == false)`

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. After you have debugged and if you still need help, please post a [mcve] to illustrate the problem. This shouldn't be your entire program. Rather it should be a new program that causes the exact same error you are asking about with the minimal amount of code. Be sure to remove all unnecessary indentation. Scrolling horizontally is incredibly annoying.

Comment: Hash is not unique.  There is small probability of duplicates.  In the IEqualityComparer there is a two stage compare.  First using hash and then doing an actual compare (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: @jdweng What's the point of your comment here? What value does it add to this discussion?

Comment: `hash` isn't actually a hash.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are adding the full URL to the file, but while checking you are comparing only with the root URL

Modify the condition

```
if (!hash.Contains(Helpers.GetRootUrl(externalUrl)))
```

to

```
if (!hash.Any(x => x.Contains(Helpers.GetRootUrl(externalUrl))))
```

Comment: I also see a few errors in the code. you are adding URL's after few modifications `make &amp; to &` and `get rid of #038;` but you are not doing this while compare. There is a chance that this will also add duplicate URL's to the file